# Firefox & chromium and other browsers

Tags: firefox, crash, browser

I have problem with launching browsers on ubuntu 20.
when I launch them, ubuntu crashes
can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by crashing? What happens?

Comment: It freezes (the ubuntu and browser) when I open browsers

Comment: Usually the browser doesn't launch at all (firefox) if your graphics card doesn't support 3D acceleration. What graphics card do you have?